# Arguments of int main() in C

Tags: c, output

Please explain the output of the following program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(i) {
    printf("i=%d\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:
i=1

Comment: It's not valid standard C, so you have to tell which compiler you are using and with what non-standard extensions.

Comment: Hint: Try running your program with a few extra parameters - say, `a.out 1 2 3` and see if anything changes. This is definitely UB, though.

Comment: How do you call it?

Comment: It looks like `i` corresponds to `argc` in the second function signature described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).  The first command line argument corresponds to the program name, so there will always be one argument, which is where `i=1` is coming from.  But it's pointless code in any case, as it doesn't conform to either signature, nor to an implementation-defined signature as specified in C99 or above, making this Undefined Behavior.

Comment: It runs in my compiler Dev C++, without any extension. I saw this code in a MCQ test.

Comment: Sure it does, because `i` apparently corresponds in type to the first parameter in the function.  It's still Undefined Behavior.

Comment: K&R syntax, defaulting to `int` when unspecified. Ouch! it works but by chance!

Comment: As an aside, I really dislike these kinds of questions on a test.  If you're going to test my knowledge, at least ask me about things I'm actually going to write.

Comment: This is a pretty bad test question. It's non-standard, so it could very well run differently when compiled with different compilers, or not compile at all. Tbh, this makes me doubt the usefulness of this test.

Comment: Once again, we see that it is _bad pedagogy_ to call implicit int, K&R function definitions, nonstandard signatures for `main`, unprototyped declarations, etc. "not valid" so long as commonly used compilers accept them without complaint in their default configurations. If you want that ever to change, you're gonna need to scare up funding for someone to go through all of GCC and Clang's backward compatibility leniencies and figure out which of them can safely be turned off in the default mode.

Comment: @zwol Not only are these constructs not "not valid", to some extent they *are* valid, and I'm glad of it.  I'm probably in a small minority, but I've got plenty of code from the 1980's and 1990's that still works perfectly well, and I'm glad that I don't have to spend time rewriting it.  Why should I have to spend time rewriting it?  It still works perfectly well!

Comment: (But I'm in the minority, I know, not only for having such code, but for appreciating this level of backwards compatibility.  These days, it seems, backwards compatibility is out of fashion, and everybody is expected to rewrite all their code every time someone decides that a breaking change will make things better, meaning that no code is stable; everybody is busy rewriting everything all the time.)

Comment: Indeed if I compile it as test.c and execute `test hello world` it ouputs `3`. I don't code like this, but some of the little utilities I write only need to have *some* argument to behave in a different way (e.g. verbose) rather than a particular argument.

Comment: The only thing this teaches is what learning material to ignore. This is niche knowledge for software and compilers that should be in a museum or in very experienced hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a hosted environment, at least, there are two valid signatures for `main`:

```
int main(void)

int main(int, char **)
```

For the second form, the traditional argument names are `argc` and `argv`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

If it can get away with it, it's reasonably for an implementation to arrange that it always initially call

```
main(argc, argv)
```

from its run-time startup code, and if the user has declared

```
int main(void)
```

just have the "extra" parameters be ignored.  (Depending on the details of the function calling mechanism in use, it may or may not be possible to pass "extra" parameters and have them be quietly ignored, without causing any problems — but it's pretty common for this to be so.)

In the code you posted, `main`'s declaration is quite different:

```
int main(i)
```

This is an "old style" (K&R1) function definition, where arguments default to type `int`.  So this is the same as

```
int main(int i)
```

But it's not clear why someone would try to declare `main` with one parameter like this.  It's nonstandard, it's not guaranteed to work, and there's no good reason for doing so. Nevertheless, if you're on a platform where the run-time startup code is always passing both arguments, and where extra arguments are quietly and harmlessly ignored, this code would likely end up receiving `argc` in its `i` parameter.

As was suggested in a comment, if you're in a position to invoke your test program from the command line, or otherwise pass it command-line arguments, you can try invoking it with different numbers of command-line arguments, and see if you get different results.

The reason you got `1` when you passed no command-line arguments is that the name of the invoked program is usually passed as `argv[0]`, so `argc` is almost always at least 1.

But as mentioned, this is nonstandard and not guaranteed to work.  It could just about as easily do nothing, or print "Rumpelstiltskin!", or crash.

Comment: `It's not clear why you did this.` -- It appears on a test, as the OP stated in the comments above.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks.  Answer updated.  And I agree with your aside about dopey test questions.

Comment: Given my cranky comment on the question re not calling this "not valid", I want to say that I fully agree with its being a bad test question.